# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'objectpath' while the package is installed

Tags: python, pip, package, interpreter, objectpath

I'm using python 3.7.1 (on windows 10) for the first time and i want to

```
import objectpath
```

I have installed the package successfully with pip using:

```
pip install objectpath
```

> Requirement already satisfied: objectpath in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.6.1)

But the code generates an error as it haven't find the object path

> import objectpath ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'objectpath'`

I'am  using the interpreter Project default(python3.7(python))

Comment: What kind of operating system do you have?

Comment: i'am using windows 10

Comment: How many python versions do you have?

Comment: i have only the 3.7.1 version on my machine. I use pycharm

Comment: Did you try `from objectpath import *`?

Comment: no i didn't.. can you please clarify to me how to use it i'am using python for the first time

Comment: This is different kind of import. Let's say that instead of importing module you are importing method/class declarations from this module. Instead of `import objectpath` try `from objectpath import *`.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Same error for me too. I have tried both types of import strategies, still getting the same error with python 3.7 on mac

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org objectpath
```